# Top reported indicators MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, join, average

Firs of all congratulations for such a great site, it always pop up on the search with the most professional answer.

I am getting around with MySql JOINS and actually trying to apply some pre process on MySql, let's get to the point:

Given those 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `reports_indicators` (
  `report_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `indicator_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reported` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`report_id`,`indicator_id`),
  KEY `fk_reports_has_indicators_indicators1` (`indicator_id`),
  KEY `fk_reports_has_indicators_reports1` (`report_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=77409 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `reports` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'untiteled'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11609 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

CREATE TABLE `indicators` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=312 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

I am trying to get the top reported indicators, that simple... but I can´t!

All I could get was a set of indicators from one single report:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM reports_indicators as ri
  INNER JOIN indicators as i
  ON i.id = ri.indicator_id
  WHERE ri.report_id=6867
  ORDER BY ri.report_id asc;
```

I know is not even close, but when I started to try AVG found out that could not fit it on the wright place.

Any help?

Thanks a lot!

bto.

Comment: What is a "*top reported indicator*"?

Comment: You `WHERE` clause specifies only a single report id, thus you will only get data related to that report id.

Comment: Please be more specific with the expected result for the query. Show an example of the columns that it must return and example values.

Answer (score 3):

This assumes that by "top reported indicator", you mean the indicators that have the most associated records in the `reports_indicators` table will be sorted to appear first:

```
SELECT 
    i.id,
    i.name, 
    COUNT(*) AS TotalReported
FROM 
    reports_indicators as ri
    INNER JOIN indicators as i
        ON i.id = ri.indicator_id
GROUP BY i.id, i.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: @eggyal Hmmm, you're right, that can't be it.  I'll change it to a `COUNT()` in hopes that was meant by "top reported indicator" until OP gives clarification.

Comment: Deleted mine and voted this up as mine became duplicate after change from `SUM` to `COUNT`

Comment: And you can add a limit clause to get the number that you actually need.

Comment: @eggyal *Sigh*... you're right again.  My success rate is 0 for 2 on this answer, so I think it's time for me to take a little break.

Comment: Hi all, @Michael Fredrickson this is it! Thanks, I need further practice JOINS...Sorry for not being specific enough, top reported indicators as you correctly stated is the top appearance of one indicator on the reports_indicators table.